# How to implement a 'free up space' button on Android?

Tags: android

I would like to create button that can navigate on system clean up screen which allow user to clear storage space. Similar to Google Play's button:

[image]

Any ideas about intent which I can fire? Or they are even different from device to device so it isn't worth effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following code:

```
  void goStorageManage(){
        Intent intent =new  Intent(Settings.ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Can I add your weChat?